# Gradient Descent returning nan in output

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

I have a data having 3 features and 1 target variable.
I am trying to use gradient descent and later minimize the RMSE

While trying to run the code, I am getting nan as the cost/error term
Tried a lot of methods but can't figure it out.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong with the calculation.
Here's the code:
`m = len(y)`

```
# calculate gradient
def grad(theta):
    
    dJ = 1/m*np.sum((Xnorm.dot(theta)-ynorm.reshape(len(ynorm),1))*Xnorm,axis=0).reshape(-1,1)
    return dJ

def cost(theta):
    J = np.sum((Xnorm.dot(theta)-ynorm.reshape(len(ynorm),1))**2,axis=0)
    return J

def GD(theta0,learning_rate = 0.0005,epochs=500,TOL=1e-1):
    
    theta_history = [theta0]
    J_history = [cost(theta0)]
    print(J_history)
    
    thetanew = theta0*10000
#     print(f'epoch \t Cost(J) \t')
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        if epoch%100 == 0:
            print('epoch', epoch, 'cost',J_history[-1])
        dJ = grad(theta0)
        J = cost(theta0)
        
        thetanew = theta0 - learning_rate*dJ
        theta_history.append(thetanew)
        J_history.append(J)
        
        if np.sum((thetanew - theta0)**2) < TOL:
            print('Convergence achieved.')
            break
        theta0 = thetanew

    return thetanew,theta_history,J_history
```

Even for the first theta value, it returns nan

```
theta,theta_history,J_history = GD(theta0)
```

[image]

Shape of my variables

[image]

Comment: What is `m` here?

Comment: m = len(y)..i updated the code too

Comment: I assume there are no missing values (`nan`) in `Xnorm` or `ynorm`?

Comment: your cost seems to be very high. did you look at your parameters and the magnitude of your gradients to make sure they're not exploding? your parameters' values might turn to np.inf and that might result in nans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable solution which we came up was since the cost was high.. it was not possible to use this approach for this solution. We tried using a different approach like simple linear regression and it worked.